# SQL Query comparing columns in separate tables and databases

Tags: mysql, sql

Alright, so I'm trying to compare two columns, in two tables, in separate databases. I am going to warn you, I quite new to SQL. I am trying to write a query to do something like this:

```
If a field in tableA column2 contains a field from tableB column1 at least once, increment a counter
```

I want to know the value of the counter. Also, when I same "contains" I mean in a `substr()` kind of way (fe. "marketplace" contains the word "market"). Can anyone help me out with this, or at least point me in the right direction?

Comment: Ummm, you don't know?  Good luck with that.

Comment: Is "counter" a field in one of the tables?  If not, what is "counter"?

Comment: I'm thinking of it in a looping logic - like how I would code this in C++ to compare 2 arrays (versus columns). I want to count the number of times that a field in tableA column2 contains a field from tableB column1 at least once.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46699/discussion-between-rick-s-and-josh-i)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you are after.  it will obviously not loop, but it accomplishes what you are trying to do.

```
select a.c2,
  count(case when a.c2 = b.c1 then 1 else 0 end) as c1count
from table1 as a 
left join
table2 as b
on a.key = b.key

group by a.c2
```

or something like that. that join will probably need some work, but it is hard to say without more information.  good luck.

Comment: Thanks, sorry for the weird syntax... I didn't know how else to word it.

Answer (score 0):

This will get you the number of times that the contents of tableB.col1 is found as part of the contents of tableA.col2:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM tableA
JOIN tableB ON tableA.col2 RLIKE tableB.col1
```

In general, SQL engines are optimized to work better with set-based logic as opposed to procedural algorithms, such as looping.